# Switching Activitys

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to switch activity's with the use of a button.

Skillz.java

```
Button b2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent();
        String packageName="marco.skillz.app";
        String className="marco.skillz.app.act2";
        myintent.setClassName(packageName, className);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
});
```

act2.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2);
}
```

When the app run in the emulator I get the following error:

```
The application "app name" (process marco.skillz.app) has stopped unexpectedly.
```

FIXED!! I feel so stupid i had  android:name=".act1" when it should be  android:name=".act2".

Thanks for all your input :P

Answer (score 1):

Please check like this

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Skillz.this,act2.class);
        startActivity(myintent);

    }
```

Add act2 activity in the manifest file

Comment: Thanks. I had put  android:name=".act1" instead of  android:name=".act2" in the manifest file. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this Skillz.java in `oncreate`

```
    Button b2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
             b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
             {public void onClick
             (View  v) { 
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), act2.class);
                      startActivity(i);
}
             });
```

Comment: No luck :( the same error still occurs. Thanks for your input ;)

Comment: yes it was i had accidentally put android:name=".act1" not android:name=".act2".

Comment: good! Normally logcat should tell you that you forgot to add the activity to manifest.xml ;)